# How can i disable copy paste options in WebView in Xamarin Forms Application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using WebView in my xamarin forms application and i want to block selection and copy-paste options in Webview
How can i achieve this?
I think it can be done by using custom renderers for both iOS and android.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebView implementation of `Xamarin.Forms` do not have a property to disable it. If you don't want to use custom renderer but having a cross-platform solution, you could disable the selection option from the `CSS` of the page loading a local `CSS` in your WebView.

This could be your `CSS`, that you can put in your Assets folder:

```
* {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

And something like that for your WebView:

```
htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlData;
webview.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```